# Convert existing Angular project to Universal, encounter 'referenceerror: navigator is not defined'

Tags: node.js, angular, server-side-rendering

I recently faced the task of converting a fairly mature angular project to SSR because I had overestimated the search power of SEO in angular projects. I'm not familiar with node, my angular project is on an apache server and uses php(slim) as the backend api, however, when I started trying to use "most of the tutorials", i.e., the first step, introducing `nguniversal/express-engine` into the project, it went well, npm did not report any errors.

Then I tried to run `npm run build:ssr` and it also worked fine. The problem is that when I run `npm run serve:ssr`, it ends up throwing a "ReferenceError: **navigator is not defined" error...**

Earlier, I built a completely clean angular project for testing, from build:ssr to run serve:ssr. Even I specified node xxxx/xxxx/main.js directly, no problem, which is obvious, because the angular project for testing is absolutely clean.

However, this does not work on my current "existing angular project". Yes, I fully understand that SSR doesn't allow for navigator or most so-called DOM manipulation, and although I'm not familiar with angular universal yet, I've previewed it and I know that's not possible, but here's the biggest problem :

***In this existing angular project, there is no any navigator operations, not even a single line of code***

In fact, main.js is also generated automatically, I can't stop it at all, I don't understand why there is "navigator" written in main.js?

I've checked many so-called solutions, including writing something in server.ts, but nothing helps, how can I continue? This is really quite desperate!

Big thank any help!

Comment: are you using any npm packages ? could be a non friendly SSR package that you use. That being said its no problem to have navigator in your code as long as it does not being run. So when navigating to your root page, you can check for code being run. and lookup if this code arrives from a component from an external library.

Comment: Yes, as this is a long developed angular project, so there are quite a lot of npm packages, the current problem is inability to run express, that is, serve:ssr script failed. All the error messages are just thrown from the main.js and I can't even try to debug

Comment: Since its in your main. you can dont have to check up against lazy loaded modules, You can just check with you imported modules in app.module, its probably in one of those who causes this issue.

Comment: The module for this project is a bit complicated, but I will create a new branch as a test. I will try to check it using the exclusion method. I will build ssr/run ssr once for each exclusion. Hopefully I can find which area is causing mail.js to produce these features. Sometimes I really love this job, especially angular, but this time I really can't be happy.